# Symfony - Doctrine createQueryBuilder from json_array

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Crete custom query in Symfony 4 and I use `createQueryBuilder()`. 
My entity have column `price_ranges type type="json_array"`

This data I store in this column

```
{
    "from": "10.10.2010", 
    "to": "10.20.2010", 
    "pricePerNight": 100,
    "minStay": 7
}
```

Want to query data by `pricePerNight` key in `price_ranges` column.

I create function but I have the following error:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 41 near 'price_ranges': Error: Class App\Entity\House has no field or association named price_ranges
```

Here is my function. Where am I wrong?

```
public function findDataByPriceRange()
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');
        $qb->select('u')
            ->where('u.price_ranges LIKE :price_ranges')
            ->setParameter('pricePerNight', 100);
        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
```

After I edit my function:

```
public function findVillasByPriceRange()
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');
    $qb->select('u')
        ->where('u.priceRanges LIKE :priceRanges')
        ->setParameter('pricePerNight', 100);
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

I get this error:

```
Invalid parameter: token pricePerNight is not defined in the query.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the same parameter name in `where()` and `setParameter()` like this

```
->where('u.priceRanges LIKE :parameterName')
->setParameter('parameterName', 100);
```